# JS Div overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Okay this is killing me, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong I have multiple divs which have a width of 350px and a height of 100px and I want to avoid them overlapping... This is the code I currently have but they are still overlapping, I don't know what I'm doing wrong

```
   <html>
<head>
    <title>WebWall</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .timeliner{
            width: 350px;
            height: 100px;
            background: #eeeeee;
            border-radius: 4px;
            background: #f8faf9; /* Old browsers */
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #f8faf9 0%, #c1cdcc 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f8faf9), color-stop(100%,#c1cdcc)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #f8faf9 0%,#c1cdcc 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
            background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #f8faf9 0%,#c1cdcc 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #f8faf9 0%,#c1cdcc 100%); /* IE10+ */
            background: linear-gradient(top,  #f8faf9 0%,#c1cdcc 100%); /* W3C */
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f8faf9', endColorstr='#c1cdcc',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
            opacity: 0.9;
            display: none;
            position: absolute;

        }
        .timeline_title{
            font-family: Arial;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 18px;
            color: #333333;
            text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
        }

        .timeline_subtitle{
            font-family: Arial;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 13px;
            color: #555555;
            text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
        }

        .timeline_text{
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 12px;
            color: #777777;
            text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var vert_array = new Array();
        var hori_array = new Array();

        function getRandomizer(a,b) {
            var y = (Math.floor( Math.random()* (1+b-a) ) ) + a;
            var check = checky(y); // 200
            if(check==1){
                return y;
            }
            else{
                getRandomizer(a,b);
            }
        }

        function getRandomizerx(a,b) {
            var x = (Math.floor( Math.random()* (1+b-a) ) ) + a;
            var check = checkx(x); // 200
            if(check==1){
                return x;
            }
            else{
                getRandomizer(a,b);
            }
        }

        function checky(y){
            for(var i = 0; i<=vert_array.length;i++){
                if(y>=vert_array[i] && y<=vert_array[i]+100){
                    return 0;
                }
                else{
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }

        function checkx(x){
            for(var i = 0; i<=hori_array.length;i++){
                if(x>=hori_array[i] && x<=hori_array[i]-350){
                    return 0;
                }
                else{
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }

        function slide_in(div){
            var y = getRandomizer(100, 600);
            document.getElementById(div).style.top = y + "px";
            document.getElementById(div).style.display="block";
            vert_array.push(y);
            var x = getRandomizerx(1, 1000);
            hori_array.push(x);
            $("#" + div).animate({
                left: x + "px"
            },1200);
        }

        function init(){
            vert_array.push(100);
            hori_array.push(1);
            slide_in('timeline_1');
            setTimeout("slide_in('timeline_2')",2000);
            setTimeout("slide_in('timeline_3')",4000);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript: init();" style="background: #111111; background-image: url('http://newevolutiondesigns.com/images/freebies/hd-wallpaper-8.jpg');">
    <div id="timeline_1" class="timeliner">
        <table width="100%" height="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr valign="top">
                <td style="padding: 10px; width: 80px;">
                    <div style="border-radius: 4px; box-shadow:inset 0 0 20px #000000; position: absolute; top: 10px; height: 80px; width: 80px;"></div>
                    <img height="80" width="80" style="border-radius: 4px; box-shadow:inset 0 0 20px #000000; background: #333333;" src="http://i1.ytimg.com/i/H-_hzb2ILSCo9ftVSnrCIQ/1.jpg?v=4f457758">
                </td>
                <td align="left" style="padding: 12px;">
                    <span class="timeline_title"></span><br>
                    <span class="timeline_subtitle"></span><br>
                    <span class="timeline_text"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="timeline_2" class="timeliner">
        <table width="100%" height="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr valign="top">
                <td style="padding: 10px; width: 80px;">
                    <div style="border-radius: 4px; box-shadow:inset 0 0 20px #000000; position: absolute; top: 10px; height: 80px; width: 80px;"></div>
                    <img height="80" width="80" style="border-radius: 4px; box-shadow:inset 0 0 20px #000000; background: #333333;" src="http://i2.ytimg.com/i/y1Ms_5qBTawC-k7PVjHXKQ/1.jpg?v=b1e249">
                </td>
                <td align="left" style="padding: 12px;">
                    <span class="timeline_title"></span><br>
                    <span class="timeline_subtitle"></span><br>
                    <span class="timeline_text"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="timeline_3" class="timeliner">
        <table width="100%" height="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr valign="top">
                <td style="padding: 10px; width: 80px;">
                    <div style="border-radius: 4px; box-shadow:inset 0 0 20px #000000; position: absolute; top: 10px; height: 80px; width: 80px;"></div>
                    <img height="80" width="80" style="border-radius: 4px; box-shadow:inset 0 0 20px #000000; background: #333333;" src="img/f###.png">
                </td>
                <td align="left" style="padding: 12px;">
                    <span class="timeline_title"></span><br>
                    <span class="timeline_subtitle"></span><br>
                    <span class="timeline_text"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

the function init() gets called when the page loads

Comment: Could you provide the relevant HTML and CSS as well?

Comment: updated it :) This is the whole file

Comment: I created a jsFiddle from this, but I have no idea what the goal is. http://jsfiddle.net/pZUbY/

Comment: I'm not explaining this very well :P but basically what I would like was a script which gives a random position for a div that has dimensions of 350x100 and that doesn't make the divs overlap...

Comment: @Lenny - They don't overlap, there is only one image shown at a time

Comment: There is a 2 second delay currently to make things easier for me to see what was happening :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that first solution didn't work. I thought it was a quick fix but... no. This should work though.

http://jsfiddle.net/fWP2u/1/

Comment: They are still overlapping I think... I'm checking this on my iPod so I don't know 100% I'll check your code tomorrow morning on my computer :)